# Is REM rendered based on a default font-size of the default browser/OS font, custom served font or actually fixed pixel?

Tags: css

Example, considering the default of the root element defined as 16 for chrome, loading a page with Segoe UI will 1 rem be the 16px size based on Segoe body? What if the font served is something else such as Inter UI? or is REM
it actually 16 pixels no matter which font, OS or browser? I took a screenshot of bootstrap 4 page https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/reboot/ and measured the font which is defined as 1em and I know it's loading Segoe UI and I came up with 16pixels

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The rem unit sets the font-size relative to the browsers base font-size, and will not inherit from its parents.

for reference https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp and https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_unit_rem

Comment: browser default font-size with is SegoUI in case of chrome windows 10? can you please clarify?